# How to compile FreeImage on Mac OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, freeimage

When trying to build FreeImage 3.1.5.4 on Mac OS X 10.8 with make `make` the following error `g++-4.0: No such file or directory`occurs. There is something wrong with the makefile regarding the compiler configuration. How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `makefile.osx` of FreeImage 3.1.5.4 is outdated for OS X versions > 10.6. See the bottom of this post for a modified version. In addition to address the issue described at [FreeImage issue tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/freeimage/patches/80/) you need to add a line to `Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfAutoArray.h`:

```
#include <cstring>
```

Makefile for OS X 10.8:

```
# -*- Makefile -*-
# Mac OSX makefile for FreeImage

# This file can be generated by ./gensrclist.sh
include Makefile.srcs

# General configuration variables:
CC_X86_64 = gcc -4.2
CPP_X86_64 = g++ -4.2
COMPILERFLAGS = -Os -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -DNO_LCMS
COMPILERFLAGS_X86_64 = -arch x86_64
COMPILERPPFLAGS = -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy
INCLUDE += 
INCLUDE_X86_64 = -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
CFLAGS_X86_64 = $(COMPILERFLAGS) $(COMPILERFLAGS_X86_64) $(INCLUDE) $(INCLUDE_X86_64)
CPPFLAGS_X86_64 = $(COMPILERPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_X86_64)
LIBRARIES_X86_64 = -Wl,-syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
LIBTOOL = libtool
LIPO = lipo

TARGET = freeimage
STATICLIB = lib$(TARGET).a
SHAREDLIB = lib$(TARGET)-$(VER_MAJOR).$(VER_MINOR).dylib
LIBNAME = lib$(TARGET).$(VER_MAJOR).dylib
HEADER = Source/FreeImage.h

.SUFFIXES: .o-x86_64
MODULES_X86_64 = $(SRCS:.c=.o-x86_64)
MODULES_X86_64 := $(MODULES_X86_64:.cpp=.o-x86_64)

PREFIX = /usr/local
INSTALLDIR = $(PREFIX)/lib
INCDIR = $(PREFIX)/include

default: all

all: dist

dist: FreeImage
    cp *.a Dist
    cp *.dylib Dist
    cp Source/FreeImage.h Dist

FreeImage: $(STATICLIB) $(SHAREDLIB)

$(STATICLIB): $(STATICLIB)-x86_64
    $(LIPO) -create $(STATICLIB)-x86_64 -output $(STATICLIB)

$(STATICLIB)-x86_64: $(MODULES_X86_64)
    $(LIBTOOL) -arch_only x86_64 -o $@ $(MODULES_X86_64)

$(SHAREDLIB): $(SHAREDLIB)-x86_64
    $(LIPO) -create $(SHAREDLIB)-x86_64 -output $(SHAREDLIB)

$(SHAREDLIB)-x86_64: $(MODULES_X86_64)
    $(CPP_X86_64) -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib $(LIBRARIES_X86_64) -o $@ $(MODULES_X86_64)

.c.o-x86_64:
    $(CC_X86_64) $(CFLAGS_X86_64) -c $< -o $@

.cpp.o-x86_64:
    $(CPP_X86_64) $(CPPFLAGS_X86_64) -c $< -o $@

install:
    install -d -m 755 -o root -g wheel $(INCDIR) $(INSTALLDIR)
    install -m 644 -o root -g wheel $(HEADER) $(INCDIR)
    install -m 644 -o root -g wheel $(SHAREDLIB) $(STATICLIB) $(INSTALLDIR)
    ranlib -sf $(INSTALLDIR)/$(STATICLIB)
    ln -sf $(SHAREDLIB) $(INSTALLDIR)/$(LIBNAME)

clean:
    rm -f core Dist/*.* u2dtmp* $(MODULES_X86_64) $(STATICLIB) $(SHAREDLIB) $(SHAREDLIB)-x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the Christoph's answer:

`GCC 4.2`, which is mentioned in the answer, is pretty much outdated and `FreeImage` compiles using `Clang` quite well. So, i would recommend switching to the `Clang` toolchain.

Comment: You're right! But I think this would be better off as a comment.